# How to delete previous folder with a variable name (Batch script)

Tags: batch-file

I have issue with Chrome update - after download update chrome dont delete and rename new files. After reload chrome it again want to relaunch for update.
I've tried to write .bat for resolve it.

I did some with batch script 
- delete old chrome.exe and chrome_proxy.exe
- reneme new_* to normal name

But I can't understand how to delete previous folder if name will change after new update.

```sh
cd /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application"

echo deleting files
del chrome.exe
del chrome_proxy.exe

echo renaming files
ren new_chrome.exe chrome.exe
ren new_chrome_proxy.exe chrome_proxy.exe
```

Script will delete previous folder with name that can change after new update.[image]

Comment: Have you considered using the date and time? the older File folder clearly shows an earlier Date modified in your provided image.

Comment: @Compo i thought about it.
1. Filter folders with name like 77.* and 78.*
2. Compare them and delete folder with older name

Comment: Considering that they have not yet created two consecutive versions beginning with the same two digits, that would be okay for now, but please consider that when version `100` comes out you couldn't rely on alphabetically sorting them, or extracting the first two characters for comparison. The dates however will always be newer than the last version.